# StAX not returning all characters in a string

Tags: java, xml, stax

I've been trying to create an XML controller class using StAX.
My problem is that I am not getting the full string of an element, instead I get small parts of the string. (note some of the content have been hidden for security reasons, these will be displayed as `{content}`)

```
Characters characters = event.asCharacters();
if (!characters.isWhiteSpace()) {
    System.out.println(characters.getData());
}
```

The above code does not return the full string.

What I expect to receive is:
`{responseType} \([0-9]+\) ACC: [0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+`

what I get is the above string in 5 individual parts:
`{responseType} \([0-9]+\) ACC: [0-9]`
`+,[0-9]+,[0-9]`
`+,[0-9]+,[0-9]`
`+,[0-9]+,[0-9]`
`+,[0-9]+`

My code:

```
public static ArrayList<SmsCommand> readXML() {
    if (init()) {
        try {
            while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
                XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();
                switch (event.getEventType()) {
                case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                    StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
                    String qName = startElement.getName().getLocalPart();
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("command")) {
                        Iterator<Attribute> attributes = startElement.getAttributes();
                        command = new SmsCommand(attributes.next().getValue());
                    }
                    break;
                case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
                    Characters characters = event.asCharacters();
                    if (!characters.isWhiteSpace()) {
                        command.addResponse(characters.getData());
                    }
                    break;
                case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
                    EndElement endElement = event.asEndElement();
                    if (endElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("command")) {
                        commands.add(command);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return commands;
}
```

As well as my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
  <command type="{command}">
    <response>{responseType} \([0-9]+\) ACC: [0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+</response>
  </command>
</root>
```

Comment: i think it's reasonable for StAX implementation to split the `CHARACTERS` value, i agree with this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4567652/2657100

Comment: @nandsito your comment is misleading since you assume `SAX` and `StAX` have equivalent implementation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems getting XML node text in StAX XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781292/problems-getting-xml-node-text-in-stax-xmlstreamconstants-characters-event)

Comment: @malat while SAX and StAX are different APIs and implementations, the issue of pulling characters partially is common to them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StAX` parser is just splitting the characters into smaller pieces in the same sequential order. You could reconstruct it with a `StringBuilder`, while adding some length check for safety as well. Or you could just set a flag to get it combined by default.

> By default a StAX parser will break (typically large) CHARACTER event
>   into pieces to avoid creating large strings. You have no control over
>   where this break occurs.
>
> You can use a factory property “javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing” to
>   control this behaviour and force it to combine adjacent CHARACTER
>   events into a single event.

Reference:

- [Stop StAX breaking CHARACTER event](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/stop-stax-breaking-character-event)

Comment: Adding “javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing” did the trick and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

You can call http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html#getElementText() when you know you have a text only XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT.

Comment: very nice approach, thanks for pointing this out. Though this is not the right solution for this scenario I will definitely keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: @Martin how we can know that its a text only element? assuming we don't know the exacte structure of the xml on runtime